# In Angular.js, where are $stateParams set?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, mean.io

I am learning Angular.js through mean.io, which has an Articles package as an example.

In the Articles controller we see a line `articleId: $stateParams.articleId`:

```
$scope.findOne = function() {
      Articles.get({
        articleId: $stateParams.articleId
      }, function(article) {
        $scope.article = article;
      });
    };
```

[See the full code here](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/packages/articles/public/controllers/articles.js#L69).

I am wondering where and how the `articleId` is set in `$stateParams`. Basically where and how do `$stateParams` get set?

Update: In this [useful link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) provided by samitha it says: "In state controllers, the $stateParams object will only contain the params that were registered with that state."

So where did `articleId` get registered "with that state"? Finding the code for this would be helpful.

Comment: it's a module `stateParams`

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: @samitha, can you actually answer the question, where is `articleId` set? In the link it says "In state controllers, the $stateParams object will only contain the params that were registered with that state." So where did `articleId` get registered "with that state"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As samitha menthoned, this code uses [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), right?

From the document, `articleId` will be set by URL.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters
https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/packages/articles/public/routes/articles.js#L50

For example, when you access to `http://<your domain>/articles/1`

then `$stateParams.articleId => 1`.